# How to write a makefile executing make one directory level up

Tags: recursion, makefile, gnu-make

Can I write a wrapper makefile that will cd one level up and execute there `make`  with all the command options I have given the wrapper?

In more detail:

1. Directory `project` contains a real Makefile with some different targets.
2. Directory `project/resources` contains the wrapper Makefile which should call Makefile in `project`.
3. When I am in my shell in directory `project/resources`, I execute

   ```
   make TARGET
   ```

   and the Makefile there just cds one directory up and calls

   ```
   make TARGET
   ```

   in the directory `project`.

Is this possible? And how?

Comment: `$(MAKE) -C <directory> <target>` calls make for target <target> in directory <directory>. So, you can probably use recipe `$(MAKE) -C .. $@` for your `all`, `debug`, `clean`... targets in the sub-directory. Beware: if the `Makefile` in the parent directory recurses in the sub-directories you could create an infinite loop...

Comment: @RenaudPacalet Trouble is when I write a make file which *just* contains `$(MAKE) -C .. $@` I get an error, because this line is not part of a recipe. However I cannot put it in a recipe: A recipe needs a target and my wrapper should be universal for all recipes in the parent Makefile...

Comment: You can use this recipe for the `%` default target.

Comment: I'd strive very hard to use a non-recursive makefile. It's blindingly fast when there's nothing to do, can get all the dependencies correct, and is much less error prone. Any recursive makefiles I've seen were abominations from line 1 to the last, but that might just be me :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a very simple `Makefile` for all your sub-directories:

```
%:
    $(MAKE) -C .. $@
```

`%` is a last resort match-anything pattern rule that will match any target... for which there is no implicit rule (GNU make has an incredibly large number of implicit rules). So, if none of your targets are covered by an implicit rule, this should work. Else you will have to tell make not to use the implicit rules it knows. This can be done (with GNU make) by calling make with the `-r` option:

```
cd project/resources
make -r <anything>
```

will call make in `project` for target `<anything>`. The main drawback is that the `-r` flag is passed to the sub-make and so the implicit rules will not apply neither in `project`, which can be a problem. If it is you can obtain the same effect by adding an empty `.SUFFIXES` target to the`Makefile` in `project/resources`:

```
.SUFFIXES:

%:
    $(MAKE) -C .. $@
```

With my version of GNU make (3.82) it works like a charm and the sub-make has all the default implicit rules.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can have a makefile which works for "any" target.

The GNU make manual discusses this in the [Overriding Part of Another Makefile](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Overriding-Makefiles) section:

> Sometimes it is useful to have a makefile that is mostly just like another makefile. You can often use the `‘include’` directive to include one in the other, and add more targets or variable definitions. However, it is invalid for two makefiles to give different recipes for the same target. But there is another way.
>
> In the containing makefile (the one that wants to include the other), you can use a match-anything pattern rule to say that to remake any target that cannot be made from the information in the containing makefile, `make` should look in another makefile. See [Pattern Rules](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Rules), for more information on pattern rules.
>
> For example, if you have a makefile called `Makefile` that says how to make the target `‘foo’` (and other targets), you can write a makefile called `GNUmakefile` that contains:
>
> ```
> foo:
>         frobnicate > foo
>
> %: force
>         @$(MAKE) -f Makefile $@
> force: ;
> ```
>
> If you say `‘make foo’`, make will find `GNUmakefile`, read it, and see that to make `foo`, it needs to run the recipe `‘frobnicate > foo’`. If you say `‘make bar’`, `make` will find no way to make bar in `GNUmakefile`, so it will use the recipe from the pattern rule: `‘make -f Makefile bar’`. If `Makefile` provides a rule for updating `bar`, `make` will apply the rule. And likewise for any other target that `GNUmakefile` does not say how to make.
>
> The way this works is that the pattern rule has a pattern of just `‘%’`, so it matches any target whatever. The rule specifies a prerequisite `force`, to guarantee that the recipe will be run even if the target file already exists. We give the `force` target an empty recipe to prevent `make` from searching for an implicit rule to build it—otherwise it would apply the same match-anything rule to `force` itself and create a prerequisite loop!

Comment: Don't really understand how this helps to write a wrapper Makefile which passes all targets through to the parent Makefile...

Comment: Uh... that's *exactly* what the example is about. Passing **all** unspecified targets through to another makefile. Combine this with `-C` and you should have your solution.

Answer (score 0):

One option: use a wrapper file to execute the commands to do that.  Just be sure your target make files don't include the child directory that has the wrapper, or else you can create an endless loop.  For example,

```
clean: 
  pushd .. && make clean && popd
```

Comment: Mmmmh, is there a way to write this universal for all recipes in the parent Makefile? So can I put the `pushd .. && make clean && popd` in the subdirectory's Makefile *without* needing a target? I might change targets in the parent Makefile and it would be great if then the wrapper Makefile in the subdirectory can stay the same.

Answer (score 0):

Using the comment of user [Renaud Pacalet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1773798/renaud-pacalet) and the [answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9064871/65889) the following one-liner is as close as I could get. The whole Makefile reads:

```
IGNORE := $(shell $(MAKE) -C .. $(MAKECMDGOALS))
```

This solutions comes with a few caveats:

- Command line option `-B` does not get passed through to the subsequent make call.
- The output of the subsequently called make process (in the `project` directory) is not printed to stdout.
- The wrapper make process reports for any given target at the end :

  > make: *** No rule to make target TARGET. Stop.